# I want to update primary key of a table with new values for the primary key

Tags: sql

I want to update primary key of my old table with new values of primary key.

Old table

```
catalogId|columnB  

000987|abc  
000765|xyz
```

New table

```
catalogId|columnB  

100001|qwe  
100002|uop
```

NOTE:
What I want to achieve is I want to update the old table with the new values i.e. 000987 must be replaced by 100001 and 000765 with 100002 and so on. There are a lot of records.

how can I write a generalized query to do the update?

Comment: On what criteria do you want to perform the update? The column B values of both tables do not match.

Comment: I have a mapping sheet which has old catalogids which are matched to new catalogids. 

I have to update the old catalogids in the database with the newly mapped new catalogids.

there is no reference columns as such. It will be direct update.

Comment: You can import that mapping sheet to table, then do a INNER JOIN with that table to perform the updates.

Answer (score 0):

First you would need to import your mapping sheet in database as table or use it as an external table.

Assuming this imported mapping table structure as

```
mapping_table
old_catalogID | new_catalogID | old_columnB | new_columnB
```

Then your update query will be something like:

```
update ot.old_table ot
  set ot.catalogId = (select mt.new_catalogID from mapping_table mt
                      where mt.old_catalogID = ot.catalogId),
      ot.columnB   = (select mt.new_columnB from mapping_table mt
                      where mt.old_columnB = ot.columnB);
```